# How to split a text lines by fixed width C#

Tags: c#, regex, split, fixed-width, textfieldparser

Does anyone know how to split this file

```
1 TESTAAA      SERNUM    A DESCRIPTION
2 TESTBBB      ANOTHR    ANOTHER DESCRIPTION
3 TESTXXX      BLAHBL
```

Each column has a fixed width and I'm planning to do it with a regex but I don't know how to do it exactly.

Having

```
{id} {firsttext} {serialhere} {description}
 4    22          6            30+
```

Someone recommend with a pattern like this (.{4})(.{22})(.{6})(.+)? then split it by split(' ') but the user stated that this won't work with a column has no value, but even that, he didn't do any example.

I heard also about the TextFieldParser but it has some issues about performance.

Can anyone tell me how to split by fixed width?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this Bing search to see if anything works for you http://www.bing.com/search?q=splitting+line+into+fixed+width+fields+c%23&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=splitting+line+into+fixed+width+fields+c%23&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=35a6d68b13594e22b05fd63428fe963b

Comment: Something like `(.{4})(.{22})(.{6})(.+)?` should work fine. What have you tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: The above suggestion was to use regular expressions as an example

List<string> result = new List<string>(Regex.Split(target, @"(.{4})(.{22})(.{6})(.+)?", RegexOptions.Singleline));

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing any reason not to, I would probably just use [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx).

Having said that, the Regex should work too.

The following example works on the input shown (rather than the numbers you've given) and assumes serial number is a required field, but may not take up its entire length + description is optional. Make adjustments following that principle if these assumptions are incorrect.

```
string input = @"1 TESTAAA      SERNUM    A DESCRIPTION
2 TESTBBB      ANOTHR    ANOTHER DESCRIPTION
3 TESTXXX      BLAHBL";

var split = input.Split('\n').Select(s => new {
        Id = s.Substring(0, 2),
        FirstText = s.Substring(2, 13),
        Serial = s.Substring(15, Math.Min(s.Length-15, 10)),
        Description = s.Length > 25 ? s.Substring(25) : String.Empty
 });
```

Or as an explanatory example with more obvious naming and a slightly clearer example for serial length:

```
int idStart = 0;
int idLength = 2;
int firstTextStart = idStart + idLength;
int firstTextLength = 13;
int serialStart = firstTextStart + firstTextLength;
int serialLength = 10;
int descriptionStart = serialStart + serialLength;

var verboseSplit = input.Split('\n').Select(s => new {
    Id = s.Substring(idStart, idLength),
    FirstText = s.Substring(firstTextStart, firstTextLength),
    Serial = s.Length > descriptionStart
               ? s.Substring(serialStart, serialLength)
               : s.Substring(serialStart) 
    Description = s.Length > descriptionStart 
                    ? s.Substring(descriptionStart) 
                    : String.Empty
});
```

The output from either:

```
Id FirstText     Serial     Description 
1  TESTAAA       SERNUM     A DESCRIPTION

2  TESTBBB       ANOTHR     ANOTHER DESCRIPTION

3  TESTXXX       BLAHBL
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your sample try this, between each item there is a single white space

```
{id} {firsttext} {serialhere} {description}
 4    22          6            30+

string target = "1    TESTAAA                SERNUM A DESCRIPTION";
List<string> result = new List<string>(Regex.Split(target, @"(.{4})(.{1})(.{22})(.{1})(.{6})(.{1})(.+)?", RegexOptions.Singleline));
```

Comment: Sorry for the late!! But I tried what you suggest but it is dividing the line in 9 pieces!!

Answer (score 1):

How about this functional approach?

Start with these arrays:

```
var lines = new []
{
    "1 TESTAAA      SERNUM    A DESCRIPTION",
    "2 TESTBBB      ANOTHR    ANOTHER DESCRIPTION",
    "3 TESTXXX      BLAHBL",
};

var splits = new [] { 2, 13, 10, };
```

The `splits` I've used are different from your question because the length of the fields in each sample line does't match your splits.

Now define a recursive function to do the splitting of each line:

```
Func<string, IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<string>> f = null;
f =
    (t, ns) =>
    {
        if (ns.Any())
        {
            var n = ns.First();
            var i = System.Math.Min(n, t.Length);
            var t0 = t.Substring(0, i);
            var t1 = t.Substring(i);
            return new [] { t0.Trim(), }.Concat(f(t1, ns.Skip(1)));
        }
        else
            return new [] { t.Trim(), };
    };
```

Finally we can write a fairly trivial linq query to pull it all together:

```
var query =
    from line in lines
    let fields = f(line, splits).ToArray()
    select new
    {
        id = fields[0],
        firsttext = fields[1],
        serialhere = fields[2],
        description = fields[3],
    };
```

The result I get is:

[image: Results]